# How to get chrono time_point from year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-chrono

I am writing a device driver that only sends time in each separate field (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond). I need to convert that into a chrono time_point and ultimately into an integer count of nanoseconds since the epoch. How can I get chrono time_point from year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond?

Using c++17;

Comment: `device driver that only sends time in each separate field` Sure. What calendar is used? Gregorian? What timezone? UTC? Daytime? Is it in GPS time? Etc. `I need to convert that into a chrono time_point and ultimately into an integer count of nanoseconds since the epoch` then is this XY question? do you care about chrono time_point at all? Or is that time_point just a "means to an end"? And if you have input in milliseconds, and want nanoseconds, no magic you can do, precision will say in milliseconds.

Comment: Fill in a `struct tm` with the values, convert that to a time_t, and then call `<CLOCK>::from_time_t`.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/system_clock/from_time_t/.  it's up to you to make sure the epochs, time zones, etc match.

Comment: try https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Answer (score 2):

You could make a little conversion function that fills a `std::tm`, creates a `std::time_t` using `std::mktime` and then calls the selected clock's `from_time_t` function (note, not all clocks have this function) and finally add milliseconds to that.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

template<class Clock = std::chrono::system_clock>
class Clock::time_point foo(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute,
                            int second, int millisecond)
{
    std::tm t{};
    t.tm_year = year - 1900;
    t.tm_mon = month - 1;
    t.tm_mday = day;
    t.tm_hour = hour;
    t.tm_min = minute;
    t.tm_sec = second;
    return Clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&t)) + std::chrono::milliseconds(millisecond);
}

int main() {
    auto tp = foo(2021,3,8,22,25,50,469);
    std::chrono::nanoseconds tse = tp.time_since_epoch();
    std::cout << tse.count() << '\n';                     // 1615242350469000000
}
```

Note that this interprets the input as the local date/time according to the computer's local time zone setting.

Comment: Note that this interprets the input as the local date/time according to the computer's local time zone setting.  This is _probably_ what the OP intended, but as I write this, that is not confirmed.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Good point! I put that in the answer.